# jquery pick a random property from an object

Tags: jquery

I need to do this:
When a button is clicked: print out a **random** set of: question, options and wait for the user to pick one of the option.

I've searched for answers on stackoverflow and other sites but still cannot figure it out.

I have 2 approaches so far:
1st approach:

```
function data(question, options, answer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.options = options;
    this.answer = answer;
}

var q1 = new data("Question 1", ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", " Option 4"], 3);
//then keep creating new var q
```

2nd approach:

```
var pool = {
    q1: {
        question: "Question 1",
        options: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"],
        answer: 2
    },
    q2: {}
}
//then randomly pick a q out of the array(?)/object pool
```

And I'm stuck here. I cannot figure out how to show a random set out of the stored sets (each set has a question, 4 options of answers), and also the set comes with a correct answer as the index of 1 of the options.

Comment: go with second approach

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. So what do I need to do next? Also, with the 2nd approach, it looks like there could be a function to add all the data to each property because it's repetitive to add each set of question.

Comment: The method `Math.random()` and accessor operator `[]` will come handy for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give you a hint to do your quiz generator, this is what ive came out as of now, the function will give you random property of the obejct, **HOWEVER** for a quiz generator you may want to filter atleast what property was already displayed or printed. For now try this and let me know If it helped you to your problem.

```
var pool = {
q1: {
    question: "Question 1",
    options: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"],
    answer: 2
},
q2: {
    question: "Question 2",
    options: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"],
    answer: 2
},
q3: {
    question: "Question 3",
    options: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"],
    answer: 2
},
q4: {
    question: "Question 3",
    options: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"],
    answer: 2
},
}

function randomIt(obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj)
  return obj[keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];
};

console.log(randomIt(pool));
```

Alsa a Jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6bvco6om/).

Comment: Thank you jhek. This does help me with the problem. Also, you're absolutely right, I need to filter the chosen set. Do you think with a var chosen = false would do it? I was trying a loop to go through all the properties of object pool but I think the function each() in jQuery can do the same. Is that true?

Comment: Oh. I think I've figured that out: when a property is chosen, I add a value to its own property: used: (from false to true).

Comment: absolutely you can do that, anyway its all about creativity, as long as it will work for you and to your requirements. Boolean is also my best solution for it though.